# Primality testing: Why is dividing a number $n$ by every integer between 2 and $\sqrt{n}$ an inefficient test?

Tags: complexity-theory, primes

In the paper "PRIMES is in P" the following is said (page 1):

> Let PRIMES denote the set of all prime numbers. The definition of prime numbers already gives a way of determining if a number $n$ is in PRIMES: try dividing $n$ by every number $m \leq \sqrt{n}$ — if any m divides $n$ then it is composite, otherwise it is prime. This test was known since the time of the ancient Greeks — it is a specialization of the Sieve of Eratosthenes (ca. 240 BC) that generates all primes less then $n$. The test, however, is inefficient: it takes $\Omega (\sqrt{n})$ steps to determine if $n$ is prime. An efficient test should need only a polynomial (in the size of the input = $\lceil \log n \rceil$) number of steps.

Firstly, isn't complexity $\sqrt{n}$ already polynomial?

Secondly, why would complexity $\lceil \log n \rceil$ represent an efficient algorithm? This seems somewhat arbitrary to me.

Comment: Try to understand the concept of [pseudo-polynomial time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-polynomial_time). It will answer your question.

Comment: In twenty seconds I can write down a number that this method won’t factor in a lifetime.

Comment: You can buy say a 60 TB hard drive for a reasonable amount of money, which stores 480 trillion bits. On that hard drive you can store one single 480 trillion bit number. log n would be 480 trillion for that number. I can buy a computer doing 10 billion operations per second easily, so 480 trillion operations don't even take a day. So it can prove primality for the largest number that you can reasonably store anywhere in a few days. That's efficient. Trial division will not prove primality for a 30 digit decimal number in that time.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The complexity is measured as a function of the size of the input.
You don't have here an array of $n$ numbers but a number $n$.
 The size of the input is $O(\log n)$ (to store a number $n$ you need $\lfloor log_2(n) + 1 )\rfloor$ bits).
Hence, $O(\sqrt n)$ is not polynomial in the size of the input.

The answer to the second question is a direct consequence. Since the size of the input is logarithmic in $n$, an algorithm with logarithmic time complexity with respect to $n$ (and therefore, polynomial wrt the size of the input) would be efficient.

As an example, consider a number $M$ of size $n$, an algorithm with time complexity $O(log^k M)$ for a constant $k$, corresponds to a polynomial time algorithm (in the size of the input) of time complexity $O(n^k)$.

Answer (score 7):

newbie's answer already explains it all. But if I had to add something to this, I'd put it in simpler words.

When you talk about a polynomial time algorithm, what you actually mean is that the running time of the algorithm is a polynomial *in the input length*. The input length is, roughly speaking, the number of keystrokes required to express the input.

To see why $O(\sqrt{n})$ is not polynomial in the input length, consider what happens when you add a new digit to the right end of your input. This requires just one extra keystroke. So, the input length goes up by just one. However, note that the *value* of the input goes up by a factor of $10$. So, now you need to do $\sqrt{10}\approx 3$ times as many divisions to check if your input is prime or not. Increasing the input length by just one results in a $3$-fold increase in work. This is clearly exponential.

The $O(\sqrt{n})$ time algorithm is an example of a [pseudo-polynomial time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-polynomial_time) algorithm. These are algorithms whose running times are a polynomial in the *numeric value* of the input, but not necessarily in the length of the input. Another common example of a pseudo-polynomial time algorithm is the dynamic programming algorithm for [$0-1$ knapsack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#0/1_knapsack_problem).

Answer (score 0):

First of, you don't need to test the even numbers.

Second of, you don't need to test the numbers which end with a zero or with a 5.

Third of, you don't need to test any numbers which are not in the primorial base 30 a multiple of $30-+ (1,7,11,13)$

Fourth of you don't need to test any numbers which are not in the primorial base 210 a multiple of $210-+ (1,11,13,17,19,23...)$

Fifth of...
Repeat.

Answer (score -3):

So what is the issue here? The algorithm clearly requires (sqrt(n)//2) divisions by the respect to the N. So if I measure complexity by the function: input number -> #of divisions, then I will get theta(sqrt(n)) complexity.

I believe the actual problem why this algorithm is inefficient that division is not a basic operation, and that the division's complexity is based on the length of divided numbers. Which I didn't see mentioned in any of the responses.

Also there seems to be a misunderstanding in expression of the complexity in "O" notation -  O(sqrt(n)) is a subset of O(n) and therefore the algorithms should be more efficient, because power of 0.5 will be less than power of 1 for all positive integers. The other thing is that all algorithms with this (sqrt) complexity can be implemented only in such a way you showed - why is that inefficient. But I state that O(sqrt(x)) <= O (x).