# How can the length of a string be $O(\log n)$?

Tags: time-complexity, python

I have just started learning about time complexities and am currently reading Logarithmic Complexity. Here's an example of a piece of code which is $O(\log n)$:

```
def intToStr(i):
    '''Assumes i is a nonnegative int Returns the string representation of i'''

    digits = '0123456789'
    if i == 0:
        return '0'
    result = ''
    while i > 0:
        result = digits[i % 10] + result
        i = i // 10
    return result
```

So this just gives is the str of an integer. `intToStr(1243)` returns `'1243'`. I completely understand that the above function is of logarithmic complexity.

In continuation,

```
def addDigits(n):

    '''Assumes n is a nonnegative int
    Returns the sum of the digits in n'''
    stringRep = intToStr(n)
    val = 0
    for c in stringRep:
        val += int(c)
    return val
```

My book says that: (emphasis added)

> **The complexity of converting $n$ to a string is $O(\log n)$,** and `intToStr` returns a string of length $O(\log n)$. The for loop will be executed $O(\operatorname{len}(\mathit{stringRep}))$ times, i.e., $O(\log n)$ times. Putting it all together, and assuming that a character representing a digit can be converted to an integer in constant time, the program will run in time proportional to $O(\log n) + O(\log n)$, which makes it $O(\log n)$.

Can someone please explain how `intToStr` returns a string of length $O(\log n)$? Doesn't it just return a string of length $n$, where $n$ is the length of the integer that we pass?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The length of the binary representation of a natural number $n$ is roughly $\log_2 n$. As an example, the number represented by the binary string $10^{n-1}$ of length $n$ is $2^n$.

Your sources are misleading. Usually $n$ is reserved for the *input length* or a related quantity, not the *input value*. If the input to a function is an integer $m$, then the input length is only $\sim \log_2 |m|$. In particular, `intToStr` actually runs in *linear* time in the input length, rather than logarithmic time.

Comment: Hi. I just edited my post to add the complete paragraph, do you still think that it is incorrect?

Comment: It is correct, just highly misleading. For a similar example, see https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/88398/primality-testing-why-is-dividing-a-number-n-by-every-integer-between-2-and.

Comment: Can we say that `addDigits()` is of linear complexity but as it calls `intToStr()` ( which is of log complexity ), the whole program is of logarithmic complexity?

Comment: `intToStr` has linear complexity.

Comment: WHAT!? `i = i // 10` boils down to the number of times we can use integer division to divide `i` by 10 before getting a result of 0. So the complexity must be O(log(i))! 
Is that explanation incorrect?

Comment: Yes, it takes $\log i$ iterations of dividing by ten to reduce $i$ to zero. So the running time is $\log i$. But the length of the input is also $\log i$, so the running time is linear when measured as a function of the input length, which is the standard way to measure it.

Comment: @DavidRicherby You said that "...the length of the input 'i' is also log(i)..." What does that mean? Isn't the length of the input `len(i)`?

Comment: @RDoe. "`len(i)`" just means "the length of `i`" so you're saying "Isn't the length of the input the length of i?" The "length" of a number is the number of digits (bits, if you're in binary) required to write it down, and the number $i$ has $\log i$ digits.

Comment: @DavidRicherby THANK YOU!!! Now I get it. So here's the last question: If the number of bits of an input `i` is log(i), how does that make the function `intToStr(i)` linear even if you measure it as a function of the input length? It still will take log(i)  iterations.

Comment: The input length is $\log i$.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question literally, yes, the code does just return a string of length $n$ where $n$ is the length of the integer that we pass. And this is the right way to think about it.

Your source, though, is using $n$ to denote the *value* of the integer, not its length.  This is an unusual thing to do and it is, in my opinion, a very bad idea when teaching the basics of algorithm analysis.  This is a point that students find fundamentally confusing, and your book seems to be contributing to that confusion, instead of reducing it.